# Create a function that accepts two dates, and returns the number of adverts that were posted between these two dates

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am having trouble with a work sheet how do I do this

```
create or alter function prac1.advert

(@date1 date, @date2 date)

returns date

begin

    return()

end;

go
```

all i need is the format so that i can just implement the values i need myself

*number of adverts in integer*

Comment: Are you using MS SQL Server or Postgresql? (Or anything else.)

Comment: `tsql` refers to Microsoft SQL Server (and your code looks like that) - but that is a completely different product than PostgreSQL. Which one are you really using?

Comment: I am using MS SQL Server

Comment: There are plenty of tutorials about writing a function in SQL server. Google and pick one.

Comment: i am just using MS SQL thats all

Comment: I do not understand, in the question it returns INT, but in the example of function DATE.  
What do you want to return ? And provide an example of dataset.

Comment: Ideally you should use an inline Table Valued Function, not a scalar function. They are much faster

Answer (score 0):

Try like this (T-SQL):

```sql
create function prac1.fn_numberOfAdvertsBetweenDates(
    @date1 date
    , @date2 date
)
returns int
as
begin
    declare @numberOfAdverts int;

    set @numberOfAdverts = (
        select
            isnull(count(*), cast(0 as int))

        from TableOfAdverts

        where DateColumn >= @date1
            and DateColumn < @date2
    );

    return(numberOfAdverts);
end;
```

Comment: Strongly recommend converting this to an inline-able TVF as scalar functions perform horribly when data is accessed. General rule of thumb, if your function has the word ```FROM``` in it, use a TVF. Inline means basically do it in 1 query. Many article examples on how it works, see this article for example https://www.sqlshack.com/sql-server-inline-table-valued-function/?msclkid=35f6e882b4fa11ecaaf3785098a4acaa

Comment: @Stephan You are right about performance, but question was about this type of function.